# Store values for matrix from winform C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

How can i store values from textbox in winforms to matrix. I took the values from the textbox and converted them to int, Now i would like to store them in a two-dimensional array.

```
int m11 = Convert.ToInt16(textbox.Text);
int m12 = Convert.ToInt16(textbox.Text);
int m13 = Convert.ToInt16(textbox.Text);
```

I can store them in a List of single dimensional array but how to store them in a two dimensional array do i have to use any for loops

```
List<Int[]> lstArray = new List<Int[]>();
int[] arr = new int[10];
arr[0] = m11;
arr[1] = m12;
arr[2] = m13;
lstArray.Add(arr);
int[,] matrixValues = new int[10,10];
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is a little unclear. Do you only have one value for all elements in the matrix? Is your matrix always 10x10?

Comment: I'd better use dataGridView for matrix input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the textbox name like `txt_0_0, txt_0_1,..txt_0_9, txt_1_0, txt_1_1,.. txt_1_9 ...n`

The textbox should be created like this

```
txt_0_0  txt_1_0  txt_2_0  txt_3_0 txt_4_0  
txt_0_1  txt_1_1  txt_2_1  txt_3_1 txt_4_1  
txt_0_2  txt_1_2  txt_2_2  txt_3_2 txt_4_2  
txt_0_3  txt_1_3  txt_2_3  txt_3_3 txt_4_3  
txt_0_4  txt_1_4  txt_2_4  txt_3_4 txt_4_4
```

then create a loop like this

```
string txtName = string.Empty;
int[,] aVal = new int[10, 10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
   {
      txtName = String.Format("txt_{0}_{1}", i, x);
      string sVal = ((TextBox)this.Controls[txtName]).Text
      int iVal = 0;
      if (int.TryParse(sVal, out iVal))
          aVal[i][x] = iVal;
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this its working but for every second value i.e for every second value i gave in the textbox, exception is coming in "string sVal = ((TextBox)this.Controls[txtName]).Text" The Exception is Object reference is not set to an instance of the object. I have given value in all the textboxes but why does this exception occur

Comment: if the value of your textbox is containing any non-numeric character then it will not convert in `int` datatype even the textbox is empty then it can throws the exception.

Comment: @Sirisha make sure the textbox is exist in your form with stored name in txtName. What is the value of txtName when error comes?

Comment: My mistake i didnt name the textboxes correctly i was able to do it with your code thank you so much